# Pandas groupby and check if value of one row within another row value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to group on the customer and match items where count is 1 with items where count is > 1 and if all the items are matched then add to new column the probable merge id. for example: customer 1, id=3 items are in id=2 so it's a match and proable merge id is 1 and Similarly for customer 2, id=7 is count 1 and items is within id=5 items, so match and probable merge id is 4.

**My Dataframe:**

```
    count custmr    id  items
    3   Customer1   1   Cabbage, beet, Okra, root
    3   Customer1   2   Apple, Banana, Mango ,Pears, leafs
    1   Customer1   3   Mango leafs
    1   Customer1   4   tomato root
    4   Customer2   5   grapes,leach,guava,pappaya
    2   Customer2   6   blackberry,blueberry
    1   Customer2   7   pappaya
```

**Expected Output:**

```
  count custmr     id        items                        probable_merge_id
    3   Customer1   1   Cabbage, beet, Okra, root   
    3   Customer1   2   Apple, Banana, Mango ,Pears, leafs  
    1   Customer1   3   Mango leafs                             2
    1   Customer1   4   tomato root 
    4   Customer2   5   grapes,leach,guava,pappaya  
    2   Customer2   6   blackberry,blueberry    
    1   Customer2   7   pappaya                                 4
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Where do you get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

First create cross join by `merge`, filter by `count=1`, convert strings to `set`s, so possible compare. Last create `Series` for `map`:

```
df1 = df.merge(df, on='custmr')
df1 = df1[(df1['count_x'] == 1)]
df1['items_x'] = df1['items_x'].str.split('\s+|,\s*').apply(set)
df1['items_y'] = df1['items_y'].str.split('\s+|,\s*').apply(set)
df1 = df1[ df1['items_x'] < df1['items_y']]
print (df1)
    count_x     custmr  id_x         items_x  count_y  id_y  \
9         1  Customer1     3  {Mango, leafs}        3     2   
22        1  Customer2     7       {pappaya}        4     5   

                                 items_y  
9   {Mango, Pears, leafs, Apple, Banana}  
22       {grapes, pappaya, leach, guava}  

s = df1.set_index('id_x')['id_y']
print (s)
id_x
3    2
7    5
Name: id_y, dtype: int64

df['probable_merge_id'] = df['id'].map(s)
print (df)
   count     custmr  id                           items  probable_merge_id
0      3  Customer1   1          Cabbage,beet,Okra,root                NaN
1      3  Customer1   2  Apple,Banana,Mango,Pears,leafs                NaN
2      1  Customer1   3                     Mango leafs                2.0
3      1  Customer1   4                     tomato root                NaN
4      4  Customer2   5      grapes,leach,guava,pappaya                NaN
5      2  Customer2   6            blackberry,blueberry                NaN
6      1  Customer2   7                         pappaya                5.0
```